# received memory Warning with Instruments

Tags: ios4, xcode-instruments

hi i am developing application with 20 UIViewControllers. application working fine but when tracking memory allocations in the instruments All allocations(Live bytes) showing bellow 10 MB .
but it producing low memory warning alert like bellow.
[image]

i can't understand what the problem is 
**can any one help me to get me out of this issue**

Answer (score 0):

Please check if view controller as a delegate to anything such as a text field or other control? If so, this will prevent the view controller from being released from memory due to a circular dependency.